# Strange timed out after delete request in iOS app

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an iOS app with rails 5.2 backend. In the app users can add likes to posts and remove them. When user removes the like from the app request is completed, however any following requests end up in a time out. After a few minutes everything get backs to normal and the app can communicate with server.

While app is throwing timed outs, the sever works fine, there is nothing special in the logs so it looks like the problem is in the app. Strangely if I try to reach the web server (while app is returning time outs) on the same network this request also gives time out (but it can be accessed with other network without a problem). Localy, even in rails production mode and on a very fast internet connection the problem does not occure (optical fibre).

Also while app is throwing time outs Xcode debugger shows that 0% of CPU is used and app is not sending / receiving any requests.

Rails server returns after delete action:

```
2019-03-08T13:40:08.849867461Z app[web.1]: [4002a8f5-d322-41b7-8e00-ac2fed71296e] Started DELETE "/api/v3/likes/remove.json?likeable_id=492&likeable_type=Post" for 37.47.129.26 at 2019-03-08 13:40:08 +0000
2019-03-08T13:40:08.861245329Z app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-08T13:40:08.861060 #296]  INFO -- :
2019-03-08T13:40:08.861279390Z app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-08T13:40:08.861184 #296]  INFO -- : Started DELETE "/api/v3/likes/remove.json" at 2019-03-08 13:40:08 +0000
2019-03-08T13:40:08.861289850Z app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-08T13:40:08.861221 #296]  INFO -- : Processing by Api::V3::Likes/likes/remove
2019-03-08T13:40:08.861336511Z app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-08T13:40:08.861278 #296]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"likeable_id"=>"492", "likeable_type"=>"Post", "format"=>"json"}
2019-03-08T13:40:08.922335770Z app[web.1]: [4002a8f5-d322-41b7-8e00-ac2fed71296e] HEADERS: {"Version"=>"HTTP/1.1", "Connection"=>"upgrade", "Host"=>"host.net", "X-Forwarded-Proto"=>"http", "X-Forwarded-For"=>"37.47.129.26, 192.168.2.57", "X-Forwarded-Port"=>"80", "X-Request-Start"=>"1552052408.848", "X-Client-Ip"=>"37.47.129.26", "X-Real-Ip"=>"37.47.129.26", "Accept"=>"*/*", "User-Agent"=>"AppName/3.8.3 (iPhone; iOS 12.2; Scale/2.00)", "Accept-Language"=>"en", "Authorization"=>"Bearer access_token", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate"}
2019-03-08T13:40:08.922492953Z app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-08T13:40:08.922411 #296]  INFO -- : Completed 200 in 61.53ms
2019-03-08T13:40:08.922522623Z app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-08T13:40:08.922465 #296]  INFO -- :
```

log form Xcode while timed out looks like:

```
2019-03-08 14:41:39.712252+0100 AppName[19582:365699] Task <FA2C12EF-434F-4BF4-AC74-F779C1A86D36>.<1> finished with error - code: -1001
2019-03-08 14:41:39.712490+0100 AppName[19582:365702] Task <FA2C12EF-434F-4BF4-AC74-F779C1A86D36>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003ffe3d0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <FA2C12EF-434F-4BF4-AC74-F779C1A86D36>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <FA2C12EF-434F-4BF4-AC74-F779C1A86D36>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://host.net/api/v3/users_registrations.json, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://host.net/api/v3/users_registrations.json, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4} [-1001]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that router was blocking all delete actions without using https.